# Changing the points of a polygon in OpenLayers

Tags: edit, openlayers, polygon, openstreetmap, points

I've built a script where you can enter a polygon with OpenLayers, because Google Maps has became a paid service. The problem I encountered, was that when you add a polygon it is there, you can delete it, but you can't change the positions of the corners just like in Google Maps. I was wondering if this is also possible with OpenLayers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenLayers Modify Feature example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/modify-feature.html). There you can see how you use `OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature` to modify shape of polygon or line or change position of point.

Comment: Thans for your reply, but I would actually like to be able to drag the corners, not to just change the size or rotate it. Because my users are allowed to draw polygons in all sizes and shapes, this isn't the best option for me.

Comment: Be sure to check the "allow vertices creation" checkbox in the example above. This option enables "dragging the corners"

Comment: Thanks a lot igorti, unchecked the other features and I could finally edit the polygon!